# Python Tabs in Different Files / Modules - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs

I can't seem to find a solution to this, and I'm really hoping someone can help my horribly archaic Python ability.

I have a few Tkinter tabs, and they are starting to get really long. They are somewhat similar in format/layout, and I am planning on adding a LOT more.

Is there no way I can hold each tab in its own file and import them? The only thing I can seem to find is importing classes and modules.

Is there a better way to do this, or am I really just adding each tabs elements in the same file?

My code looks like this so far:

```
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(win)

firstTab = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(firstTab, text='First Tab')
tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

secondTab = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(secondTab, text='Second Tab')

thirdTab = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(thirdTab, text='Third Tab')
```

And then when I add stuff to a tab I do something like:

```
firstTabLabel=ttk.Label(firstTab, text="First Tab Purpose: \n " \
    "a bunch of junk I'm providing to the people " \
    "because reasons, and requirements")
    firstTabLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=5, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)
```

Also with that "pack" on the first one, I'm not 100% sure what that is.

I wasn't sure that I could call it like a class, as I'm not really passing anything to it to do anything, other than what's in the tab section.

Comment: Please include some code that shows roughly what your issue is as I imagine there will be some way that will let you import things.

Comment: It's fairly typical to encapsulate chunks of one's UI as a class. If you do that, then importing should be easy, since you've already found information on importing classes.

Comment: Sorry, I added a bit of the code. I just assumed I'm so lost that what I'm asking is some basic thing everyone knows but me.

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do, it works like any other python code.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. I think then I'm a little confused. From what I'm learning I would import something at the top:

      import whatever *

and then I would call pieces of it for use later in my code... whatever methods I wanna use.

Am I just writing my code, and then placing those 'imports' where I want in the code?

Comment: I would recommend finding a python tutorial about how to use modules. For example, [Structuring Your Project](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) or [Python Modules and Packages – An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/)

Comment: I think maybe I'm not understanding importing, or not making my desires clear... I was wondering if I could take a chunk of code, and place it in a different file, and import it into the main code as though it were there. From what I gather when looking into this, including the links provided by Bryan, they are more like "importing classes, so you can use the methods in those classes to do things." That's not what I'm hoping to do. So, if I were to take the chunk of code I want to separate, and then call it a class, and then "import ThatFile.py" I get all sorts of errors.